# Apply rank in permutation of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 12, 33, 41, 52, 69, 7.2, 8.9, 9.91]
l2 = [45, 51]
```

I need to get all possible combinations (without repetition) from `l1` with size equals the length of `l2`. Then apply a ranking metric into `l2` and `l1` (for each combination). Finally I need to get the closest metric wrt. `l1` and `lx` (`lx` being the permuted list).

What I tried so far (it's more like a pseudo-code so far):

```
import numpy as np

def apply_metric(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())

l1 = [0, 1, 12, 33, 41, 52, 69, 7.2, 8.9, 9.91]
l2 = [45, 51]

for item in l1:
    #do the possible combinations
    temp_result = apply_metric(np.array(l2), np.array(permuted_items))
```

output:

```
best metric = 0 (identical)
best list = [45, 51]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools permutation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to obtain your permuted list and then apply the metric.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

def apply_metric(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())

l1 = [0, 1, 12, 33, 41, 52, 69, 7.2, 8.9, 9.91]
l2 = [45, 51]

temp_dict = {}
for elements in it.permutations(l1, len(l2)):
    temp_result = apply_metric(np.array(l2), np.array(elements))
    temp_dict.update({temp_result : list(elements)})

print(f"Best metric: {min(temp_dict)}")
print(f"Best list: {temp_dict[min(temp_dict)]}")
```

Which yields:

```py
Best metric: 2.9154759474226504
Best list: [41, 52]
```

Comment: thnks very much